# Is there a way to grab the title of an unsaved post in Wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress plugin which allows me to choose the proper upload folder regarding the custom post type, taxonomies terms and the title.

I can grab each kind of data when the post is saved, no problem. But how to grab for example a title of a post which hasn't been published?

I tried $_POST, by adding first a name in the title textarea field of WordPress (because it hasn't one) but this totally broke my upload filter with an internal error 500.

I have a partially working code. In a PHP file, I'm enqueuing this Ajax script:

```
function get_unposted_post_title( $hook ) {
    if ( ($hook == 'post-new.php') || ($hook == "post.php" && $_GET['action'] == "edit") ) {
        echo "<script>
            function posturl(title, url) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    data: title,
                    success: function(title, url) {
                        console.log(title);
                    }
                });
            }
            setInterval( function() {
                var title = $('#post-title-0').val();
                var url = '" .GIA_PLUGIN_URL. "test.php';
                posturl(title, url);
            }, 5000);
        </script>";
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'get_unposted_post_title', 10, 1 );
```

Then, in the root of my plugin, I have created a test.php file:

```
<?php
    $keys = array_keys($_POST);
    if(isset($keys) && !empty($keys[0])) {
        print_r( $keys[0] );
    }
?>
```

This function displays the updated title in the console.log as expected.

However, I'm unable to grab `$keys[0]` without making the upload filter crashed. Uploaded files are properly moved with the updated path of my filter, except for the last folder which must have a sanitized version of the post title. I'm hooking into `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` and `wp_handle_upload`.

If you look at the provided code, I should be able to grab keys[0]... but the problem is that keys[0] give me 'name'... keys[1] give me 'action', keys[2] give me 'wp_nonce'. I don't know why I can't grab keys[0] correctly, it seems that $keys of my test.php isn't updated with a proper value for the key 0.

Comment: This sounds kinda funny to have such comments, when I basically started from the point 0 (Ajax is an unknown world yet). Whatever, I have advanced a bit with other forums and I can now to says that Ajax is the solution. That was the starting point, but none of you seems to care. Now, I have accomplished half of the work, with a function that works partially (see updated OP with code).

Answer (score 0):

Why using Ajax if you can use direct MySQLI using the wp_db ?

You can retrieve it the same way as you currently doing it with published one.
If you grab it using MySQLI, there is a column called "**post_status**"

https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what I mean by "before the post has been published", in facts it's "before the post has been submitted". In other word, just after clicking on the "add new post". Tell me if I have wrong, but nothing is saved in the db before the first autosave, and the user must have autosave enabled on his installation. I can try with Auto-Draft status to see what I can grab from it, but like I said previously, if the user has disabled it, it will be useless.

Comment: That's why I expected to use Ajax, because it seems the only solution (from my knowledge) to retrieve field's data with jQuery, in order to make them work with a php code (my upload filters).